# cloudera - how to allocate resources for different users

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I am using cloudera 6.3 and trying to achieve following things.

1. all the users who are running interactive queries should not get more than 20% of resources
2. Functional id which is used for getting data through Imapala should not get 30% of resources
3. functional is's which are being used for ETL should get minimum 70% of resources, however if required should take resources from above two.

What should I need to do ?

1. do I need to configure dynamic resource pool for `1` and `2` ? or do I need `yarn queue`
2. for `points 3` do I need to configure resouce pool from imapala admission control ?

What does this means ? what does **root.default** and **root.users** represents ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

`root` is the root queue, as the name suggests.
`root.default` and `root.users` are its sub-queues (you can tell by the fact there is the prefix `root.`).

Honestly I'm not sure that Impala uses YARN to manage its resources though